# Idea behind choosing $\small f(x)$ as $c^{s}x^{p-1} \frac{[\theta(x)]^{p}}{(p-1)!}$ in the proof that $\pi$ is transcendental

Tags: real-analysis, transcendental-number-theory

I am going through the article at this [link](http://sixthform.info/maths/files/pitrans.pdf), where the author proves that: "$\pi$ is $\text{transcendental}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$". Although, I understand the proof, I have some doubts.

- At page $6$, the author defines a new function $f(x)$ as $$f(x) = c^{s}x^{p-1} \frac{[\theta(x)]^{p}}{(p-1)!}$$ Can anyone tell me what is the motivation behind defining $f(x)$ in this manner.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_function

Comment: This question should be closed and deleted since the OP has breached netiquette rules by crossposting, cf http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72720/idea-behind-choosing-fx-as-fx-csxp-1-frac-thetaxpp-1

Comment: @Chandrasekhar: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netiquette

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been answered on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72720/idea-behind-choosing-fx-as-fx-csxp-1-frac-thetaxpp-1